# Magical Records Update already Fetched Data

Tags: ios, magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.1

This is database design with to-many relations.This is my method

```
-(void)fetchChannelData:(id)responseObject{

            [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
                NSArray *channels = [responseObject objectForKey:@"channels"] ;
                for (NSDictionary *channelStack in channels) {
                    NSLog(@"Tenant id %@",[[ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] valueForKey:@"test"]);
                    ChannelsData *channels = [ChannelsData MR_importFromObject:channelStack inContext:localContext];
                    [channels setCategory:[[channelStack valueForKey:@"category"] firstObject]];
                    [channels setTenantID:[[ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] valueForKey:@"test"]];

                    NSArray *channelLogo = [channelStack objectForKey:@"channelImages"] ;
                    for (NSDictionary *channelLogoStack in channelLogo) {
                        ChannelImages *images = [ChannelImages MR_importFromObject:channelLogoStack inContext:localContext];
                        [channels addImagesObject:images];
                        [images setChannelID:channels.channelID];

                    }
                }
            } completion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError *error) {
                if (contextDidSave) {
                    [self fetchListing];

                }
            }];





}
```

Where I am importing my data. I have dropdown where I selected different API points for specific data. All fetching different data.Now issue is that when I launch my app again service is again called and instead data is updated it insert it again.I already Used relatedByAttribute on each entity letting their "ID" be the primary key.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjBlv.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjBlv.png)

Comment: Hi. If an entity already exists in the DB so You should load it from DB, e.g. `[CnannelData MR_findFirstWithPredicate:<predicate with ID> inContext:localContext]` instead `[ChannelsData MR_importFromObject:channelStack inContext:localContext]`.

Comment: Well whenever my app opens or logins Api's are being called now sometime the data is updated but not full data but it returns full JSON with previous records.Now instead of updating the existing records it insert them as new objects

Comment: If your server api does not support the incremental cache (it's means e.g. when you will should transfer the last update date in the request and the server will compute the changes), so just remove the previous records and then insert it again. Or do a manual merge changes..

Comment: And what about the relatedByAttribute thing in Magical Records.Will it be worth it to use it and how to use that